# Rename files increasing as they upload - PHP

Tags: php, file, upload, rename, auto-increment

I need to give incresing number to files as the upload. I am usinf SFWUpload. I have this code:

```
mkdir("../../imagenes/".$codigo , 0777);
$i = 1;
$nombre = $codigo.'_'.$i.'.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], "../../imagenes/".$codigo."/".$nombre);
chmod("../../imagenes/".$codigo."/".$_FILES['Filedata']['name'], 0777);
```

The $codigo is the code, for example 101213, so i need the pictures to upload like 101213_1.jpg, 101213_2.jpg, 101213_3.jpg, and so on.

The problem is that SWFUpload runs the php ONCE per picture, so i can not use a foreach loop (I guess).

I need the script to check if the file exists and write the next. For example, if 101213_4.jpg exists, then write 101213_5.jpg.

Can you help me how can I do this.?? I am novice at php, and tried everything.! :(

Thanks in advance

Roberto

Comment: Show us your "everything" attempt, then we can start from there :)

Comment: save the number somewhere and use that number

Comment: The "everithing" is count files, check if file exists, even the use of session, but nothing worked.! :(

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.! The point is "how". I am going to try the solution that "eagle" wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... you can try to get the current number of files on the folder and get `$i` from there:

```
mkdir("../../imagenes/".$codigo , 0777);
$i = count(glob("../../imagenes/".$codigo.'_*.jpg')) + 1;
$nombre = $codigo.'_'.$i.'.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], "../../imagenes/".$codigo."/".$nombre);
chmod("../../imagenes/".$codigo."/".$nombre, 0777);
```

Try that code...

Comment: This worked.! Thanks.!! I made this change to this line of code.!!

    $i = count(glob("../../imagenes/".$codigo."/*.jpg")) + 1;

Thanks.! ;)

Comment: What happens when two people try to upload at the same time?

Comment: I think about that... but how you avoid that race condition between PHP processes? maybe using semaphores? sem_get, sem_acquire, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function I use:

```
function cleanup_name($name){ //accepts name and cleans it up.
$finalDir='/home/username/uploads';

# Go to all lower case for consistency
$name = strtolower($name);
//echo("Name is $name<br>");

$matches=split('\.',$name);
foreach ($matches as $key=>$value){
$exkey=$key;
$exvalue=$value; //if there is more than one period, this will find the actual extension.
//echo("Key $key|$exkey Value $value|$exvalue<br>");
}

if ($exkey<1){die('The file must have an extension.');}
$extension=".".$exvalue;
$loop=0;
while ($loop<($exkey)){
if ($loop<($exkey-1)){$matches[$loop]=".".$matches[$loop];} // this puts extra periods back into the string, but the borrowed code will replace them with underscores.
$stem.=$matches[$loop];
$loop++;
}

//echo("Stem is $stem<br>");
//echo("Extension is $extension<br>");

# Convert whitespace of any kind to single underscores
$stem = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $stem);

# Remove any remaining characters other than A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _
$stem = preg_replace('/[^\w]/', '', $stem);

# Make sure the file extension has no odd characters
if (($extension != '') &&
  (!preg_match('/^\.\w+$/', $extension)))
{
  echo("odd characters in extension");
  //die("Bad file extension");
  return FALSE;
}

$safeExtensions = array(
'.zip',
'.psd',
'.pdf',
'.jpg',
'.jpeg',
'.gif',
'.rar',
'.gz',
'.ai',
'.eps',
'.bmp',
'.pub',
'.xls',
'.doc',
'.wpd',
'.rtf',
'.tiff',
'.tif',
'.pcx',
'.ttf',
'.png',
'.txt',
'.mp3',
'.avi',
'.mov',
'.wav'
);

if (!in_array($extension, $safeExtensions)) {
  echo("Extension &quot;$extension&quot; not approved.");
  //die("File extension not approved");
  return FALSE;
}

# Search for a unique filename by adding a number to the
# stem (first we try without, of course)

$suffix = '';
while (file_exists($finalDir."/".$stem.$suffix.$extension)) {
  if ($suffix == '') {
    $suffix = '0';
  } else {
    $suffix++;
  }
}

# Put the full name back together
$name = "$stem$suffix$extension";
return $name;
}
```

Pay special attention to the section with this: " while (file_exists..."

Comment: use comment, don't send answer;-)

Comment: The problem is that you have loops here.. With loops it is easy to code incremental, but in my case, i can't use loops. Thanks anyway.! xD

Comment: I think you mis-understand what the file does. It only loops enough to find the right filename, then writes the one file. `$suffix = ''; while (file_exists($finalDir."/".$stem.$suffix.$extension)) {   if ($suffix == '') {     $suffix = '0';   } else {     $suffix++;   } } ` This is really the only part you need, but I thought my variable names would make more sense in context.

Comment: Looks like you have a race condition if two people try to upload at the same time.